# Which application servers are Java EE 6 (Full Profile) compliant?

Tags: java, java-ee-6, application-server

I know that Glassfish supports Java EE 6 Full Profile since version 3, but which other servers do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition#Java_EE_6_certified only Glassfish and the commercial version does at the moment.

WebSphere should be on its way, and you have more options if you only need the web profile.